# How to store multiple objects in a cell of a grid

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list, hashmap

Context: I have a grid-based board game which places various objects onto a grid. Currently, you can only have one object in any single location stored in an array. There is also a Location class which maps the current positions of each object. Objects can move around the board and run various actions but they can never overlap each other. I would like to be able to have objects go ontop of each other.

Below I have a class which builds a grid of rows and columns which currently only contains one object per cell. I am trying to work out how I would be able to store multiple objects per cell rather than just the one?

The reason for this is that when the grid is built only one object is able to be placed onto one cell at any one time. I was thinking of using a List to store the objects, but then how would I go about implementing this?

```
/**
 * Represent a grid of cells.
 * Each cell is able to store a single object.
 * TODO: Needs to be multiple objects in a single cell
 */

public class Cell
{

 // A random number generator for providing random locations.
 private static final Random rand = Randomizer.getRandom();

 // The rows and cols of the grid.
 private int rows, cols;

private Object[][] cell;

 /**
  * Create a grid of the given values.
  * @param rows The rows of the cell.
  * @param cols The cols of the cell.
  */
 public Cell(int rows, int cols )
 {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    cell = new Object[rows][cols];
 }

 public void clear() 
 {
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            cell[row][col] = null;
        }
    }
 }

 /**
  * Place an Object at the given location.
  * If there is already an Object at the location 
  * TODO: NEEDS TO BE ABLE TO STORE MULTIPLE OBJECTS
  * @param Object The Object to be placed.
  */
 public void place(Object object) {
    Location location = object.getLocation();
    cell[location.getRow()][location.getCol()] = object;
 }

 public Object getObjectAt(int row, int col)
 {
    return cell[row][col];
 }

 public int getRows()
 {
    return rows;
 }

 public int getCols()
 {
    return cols;
 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is an "Object"? Is it an Image, an Icon, a Swing component? Is it something you paint? Without understanding the basic concept of your current implementation we can't suggest how to improve the implementation.

Comment: Can you create an object that wraps around these multiple objects?

Comment: The object is just a position within the grid which then get's filled with a colour and an image inside a JPanel view.

Comment: @JoeC Maybe, I was hoping this would be as simple as changing the Cell to hold a List or Collection?

Comment: @NoDirection, `The object is just a position within the grid` - so don't call it Object. Object is the Java root class. You can't add just any object to your grid. `get's filled with a colour and an image` - so how to you expect to display multiple game pieces? If each game piece has its own color and image, how would you stack them. The top one would hide the bottom one?

Comment: @camickr Ok so I've created a class called GamePiece with will replace Object[][]. But how can I store multiple game pieces in a cell?

Comment: `But how can I store multiple game pieces in a cell?` - like you suggested earlier you can add an ArrayList which contains 1 or more GamePieces to the Cell.

Comment: @camickr how would I implement that? And what would I need to do to my constructor?